# Is it reasonable asking employer to drop employee benefit plan probation period?

Tags: hiring, benefits, canada, probation

I was contacted by an employer and succesfully passed their hiring process. So now we are negotiating on salary and terms. I am currently employed and have my employee benefits plan. I do not want to lose it for over three months when switching over to the new place.

Is it reasonable to try convincing employer dropping the benefits probation period?

Comment: If it wasn't a big deal then they probably wouldn't be doing the whole 3 month thing. They might do it as long as you sign some papers stating you won't leave before then. Who knows?

Comment: What type of benefits are you asking about specifically? Retirement plan? Health? Fringe?

Comment: Health plan related

Comment: Canada, Ontario

Comment: Can we please justify downvotes

Answer (score 7):

It's reasonable to try, sure. The chances of you getting that changed are probably pretty slim.  Most companies that I have experience with fall back on "it's policy" or "our insurance company mandates..." whether it's true or not. I've tried several times and have not been successful once.

You can give it a shot, but I wouldn't press it too much.  You don't want any blowback from this getting to your hiring manager and be viewed as "difficult" before you even start.

Comment: Have you asked for more money to cover the costs?

Answer (score 5):

I think it is reasonable, but you may find the employer has reasons other than just the cost for 3 months benefits. Their insurance providers may have established these requirements.

If they decline, ask for an increase in salary or some sort of signing bonus to cover your 3 months of expenses (COBRA?).

Everything is negotiable, but it is not the best negotiation to ask for a significant increase than what is being offered without being able to justify it in return.

In this case, they know they're competing against your current employer to get you to move to their company, so don't feel like you have to adhere to what the current market will bare. Everybody doesn't get the average salary.

Comment: There is no COBRA-equivalent in Canada, but asking for a signing bonus to make up for increased expenses makes sense. You could even call it a relocation package instead of a signing bonus. After all, willingly relocating from one employer to another shouldn't cost you extra money. And what you would be asking for is not so much a bonus windfall of money as it is a way to maintain your existing lifestyle, your current doctor, your current level of care, and a way to make up for the expected shortfall during those three months.

Comment: Don't ask, require this to be covered.  You can phrase your negotiation like this: "Your current offer is a `$x` increase, but requires me to cover 100% of various benefits for 3 months at a cost of `$y`.  So your offer is really `$x - $y`. I'm looking for more than `$x`, and `$x-$y` is below that.