# Probation period when going from contract to permanent

Tags: negotiation, contracts, probation

Related to [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/66781/is-it-reasonable-asking-employer-to-drop-employee-benefit-plan-probation-period) question, I'm assuming waiving of probationary period by default when going from contract to permanent is entirely company specific.

In instances where this is not the default, would attempting to negotiate away the probation period give the employer a negative impression?  I would think this is asking them to remove some of their protections from having to keep a bad hire but in my experience many benefits are tied to completion of probationary period.

Note: Not talking about places with "at will" employment where probation doesn't offer the employer any additional protection.

Answer (score 1):

No. Absolutely not.

If your contract time was short, for example, only 3 months, and there is a company standard of at least a half year of probation, then it is ok if they want a further 3 months of probation time. But it is a rare case.

What I think the following possibilities:

1. I think that your employer wants to combine the advantages of the contract (they can always fire you, you are on continuous pressure a so work better) with the employment (-> lower wages). Employing somebody for a probation time, it would combine these advantages for him (and also the disadvantages, for you).
2. It is also possible, that there are company standards which you manager can't avoid (or he can only do with great difficulty). In this case, you can consider your probation time as a theoretical thing: you hadn't got the offer, if they wouldn't hire you.

How to decide between them, it can be decided only by you.

*Asking* something you can always do. At least it won't be accepted. I would suggest to not leave a company only because they didn't give your dream offer. But feel yourself entitled to look for a better one.

And also don't forget: being on probation time, it also means that *you* can always leave. For example, if you got a better offer.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to say whether it would give an employer a negative impression or not, but the best way to minimize that possibility is to **explain your reasons** for wanting to eliminate the probation.

In my cases, my reasons for having wanted to eliminate probation directly match and therefore conflict with theirs.  For me, the main reason to get rid of the probation was for benefits to start sooner.  That was also their reason to keep it. If they drop my probation, they have to start paying benefits that much sooner.

I've tried several times and never been successful. Having said that, I've never wanted it so badly as to force the issue either.